# Get the first instance of a row using MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

**EDITED:**

I have this query wherein I want to **SELECT** the first instance of a record from the table **petTable**.

```
SELECT id, 
    pet_ID, 
    FIRST(petName), 
    First(Description) 
FROM petTable 
GROUP BY pet_ID;
```

The problem is I have huge number of records and this query is too slow. I discovered that **GROUP BY** slows down the query.  Do you have any idea that could make this query faster? or better, a query wherein I don't need to use **GROUP BY**?

Comment: Does your table not have a Primary Key? If pet_ID is the primary key then there is no need of using First as there should not be more than 1 record for the same pet.

Comment: @paulFrancis , I just updated my post . Suppose I have id as primary key and    pet_id may occur more than once in the table

Comment: use of DISTINCT also makes the query too slow

Answer (score 2):

*"The problem is I have huge number of records and this query is too slow. I discovered that **GROUP BY** slows down the query. Do you have any idea that could make this query faster?"*

**And an index on `pet_ID`**, then create and test this query:

```sql
SELECT pet_ID, Min(id) AS MinOfid
FROM petTable
GROUP BY pet_ID;
```

Once you have that query working, you can join it back to the original table --- then it will select only the original rows which match based on `id` and you can retrieve the other fields you want from those matching rows.

```sql
SELECT pt.id, pt.pet_ID, pt.petName, pt.Description
FROM
    petTable AS pt
    INNER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT pet_ID, Min(id) AS MinOfid
        FROM petTable
        GROUP BY pet_ID
    ) AS sub
    ON pt.id = sub.MinOfid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Query could change as,

```
SELECT ID, pet_ID, petName, Description
FROM petTable
WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT Min(ID) As MinID FROM petTable GROUP BY pet_ID);
```

Or use the TOP clause,

```
SELECT petTable.petID, petTable.petName, petTable.[description]
FROM petTable
WHERE petTable.ID IN
   (SELECT TOP 1 ID                            
   FROM petTable AS tmpTbl                              
   WHERE tmpTbl.petID = petTable.petID        
   ORDER BY tmpTbl.petID DESC) 
ORDER BY petTable.petID, petTable.petName, petTable.[description];
```