# Access SQL to return only first or last occurence by date

Tags: sql, ms-access

First of all, I don't have many experiences with SQL and I have spent a lot of time trying to make it work. Please help.

I have [original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYOIW.jpg) from access database which contains columns: `date`, `time`, `EP` (point of entry), `ID` and rest of columns are just informational. **No primary key**, **Change of table is last solution.**

```
DateOS      TimeOS     EP    ID    Val1    Val2    Val3     Val4
1.2.2017    1:00:02    in    15    6280    blue    line1    s
1.2.2017    3:00:06    in    15    6280    blue    line1    s
1.2.2017    4:00:08    in    16    3147    red     line2    s
1.2.2017    5:00:10    out   20    6280    white   line3    c
1.2.2017    6:00:12    out   20    6280    white   line3    c
2.2.2017    2:00:04    in    16    3147    red     line2    s
```

I need to get only **first** (green in [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP59R.jpg))

```
DateOS      TimeOS     EP    ID    Val1    Val2    Val3     Val4
1.2.2017    1:00:02    in    15    6280    blue    line1    s
1.2.2017    4:00:08    in    16    3147    red     line2    s
1.2.2017    5:00:10    out   20    6280    white   line3    c
```

/ **last** (red in [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP59R.jpg)) occurences that have unique combination of EP and ID.

```
DateOS      TimeOS     EP    ID    Val1    Val2    Val3     Val4
1.2.2017    3:00:06    in    15    6280    blue    line1    s
1.2.2017    6:00:12    out   20    6280    white   line3    c
2.2.2017    2:00:04    in    16    3147    red     line2    s
```

I got ideas from:
[Get the first instance of a row using MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952004/get-the-first-instance-of-a-row-using-ms-access)

So far I have this (min function for first / max function for last):

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(pt.DateOS, 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS DateOS, 
    FORMAT(pt.TimeOS, 'HH:mm:ss') AS TimeOS, 
    pt.EP, pt.ID, pt.Val1, pt.Val2, pt.Val3, pt.val4
FROM [test07_dupl2] AS pt 
WHERE TimeOS 
IN
(
SELECT
    MIN(TimeOS) AS MinDateTimeOS 
FROM [test07_dupl2]
GROUP BY EP+ID
)
```

And this is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ler6.jpg). It is considering just TimeOS. Second line does not belong there, because it is later date.

```
DateOS      TimeOS     EP    ID    Val1    Val2    Val3     Val4
1.2.2017    1:00:02    in    15    6280    blue    line1    s
2.2.2017    2:00:04    in    16    3147    red     line2    s
1.2.2017    5:00:10    out   20    6280    white   line3    c
```

The problem is that I need to consider `DateOS + TimeOS`. So I tried to write `MIN(DateOS + TimeOS)` and also create new column with value `DateOS + TimeOS` but both returned empty table. I'm not sure if I made some mistakes, or this is wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for handling this is to check that no records exist *before* the given record.  This uses `NOT EXISTS`.

The logic is a bit complicated because the date/time is in two different columns.  But for the first record:

```
SELECT pt.*
FROM [test07_dupl2] AS pt 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [test07_dupl2] AS pt2
                  WHERE pt2.EP = pt.EP AND pt2.ID = pt.ID AND
                        (pt2.DateOS < pt.DateOS OR
                         pt2.DateOS = pt.DateOS AND pt2.TimeOS < pt.TimeOS
                        )
                 );
```

For the last, the final condition would be:

```
                        (pt2.DateOS > pt.DateOS OR
                         pt2.DateOS = pt.DateOS AND pt2.TimeOS > pt.TimeOS
                        )
```

Comment: It's working perfectly! It's funny that it took me 15min to compose this post and you have right aswer with blink of an eye.

Comment: @StanaMacala . . . It actually wasn't that fast ;)  MS Access is rather limited in its functionality compared to other databases, so I actually had to think about this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `DISTICT` function to code from @Gordon Linoff
to make sure that also duplicate lines with same date and time are gone.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM[SIMASSIST].[dbo].[TestDupl] AS t
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM[SIMASSIST].[dbo].[TestDupl] AS t2
    WHERE t2.EP = t.EP AND t2.ID = t.ID AND
    (
        (t2.DateOS < t.DateOS OR t2.DateOS = t.DateOS) AND 
        (t2.TimeOS < t.TimeOS)
    )
)
```